# Usage of the definite article "the"

Tags: definite-article

Is it advisable to use "the" in the following sentence?

> The decision to take this challenge should be made based on **the**
> simultaneous consideration of its pros and cons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I (an AME speaker) would probably drop the "the" (also substitute "upon" for "on") but this is really a very finicky matter of style rather than an issue of grammar. The sentence as-is does a fine job of imparting the desired substance.